# How to receive touch events with linux input subsystem?

Tags: android, events, touch, kernel, arm

I 'm writing a code in pure c (no java or JNI available) for android to read touch events directly from linux input events (/dev/input/*).

The problem is that I cannot find any documentation for linux touch events interface . how events are reported ? How to retrive them ? Isn't there any documentation for linux touch events?

Edit : I have also took a look at linux/input.h but there is'nt any special  struct for touch events.

Comment: See: [input.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input.h), [multi-touch doc](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt) and [Section 5 of input.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/input/input.txt).  You generally get a `SYN` followed by either `ABS_X` and `ABS_Y` or the `REL_X/Y` counter-parts.  So you get three events for one touch.  The `SYN` marks one to the next.